# Why doesn't my Android Manifest support Samsung Galaxy Note 2

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have the following manifest to build my app and found out that Google Play doesn't want my app to publish on the Samsung Galaxy Note 2, but does want to publish on the Galaxy Note 1.

What do I need to change to get it to work on the new Galaxy Note and is there a test application that can tell me the supported devices before I have to upload the APK to the Google Play Store?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="${YYAndroidPackageName}" android:versionCode="${YYAndroidVersionCode}" android:versionName="${YYAndroidMajorVersion}.${YYAndroidMinorVersion}.${YYAndroidBuildVersion}" android:installLocation="auto">

  <!-- AdMob SDK permissions -->  
  <!-- uses here -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  ${YYAndroidManifestPermission}

  <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

  <!-- application -->
  <application android:name="${YYAndroidPackageName}.RunnerApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name="${YYAndroidPackageName}.RunnerActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="${YYAndroidOrientation}" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="${YYAndroidPackageName}.RunnerPreferenceActivity" android:label="@string/menu_settings">
    </activity>

    <!-- services -->
    <service android:name="RunnerBillingService" />
    ${YYAndroidManifestServices}

    <!-- activities here -->
    ${YYAndroidManifestActivities}

    <!-- receivers here -->    
      ${YYAndroidManifestReceivers}

    <!-- This is XPeria Play specific, we have decided to make this standard though for all applications, just in case -->
    <meta-data android:name="xperiaplayoptimized_content" android:resource="@string/xperiaplayoptimized_content" />
    <meta-data android:name="game_display_name" android:resource="@string/app_name" />
    <meta-data android:name="game_icon" android:resource="@drawable/icon" />

    <!-- meta-data here -->
    ${YYAndroidManifestMetadata}

  </application>
</manifest>
```

The Manifest comes from GameMaker Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

galaxy note 2 has normal screen, not xlarge or large

Comment: No. It's a large screen. http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note_ii_n7100-4854.php

Comment: @eightx2 it should be defined in manifest as normal screen. I know it`s specs

Comment: Okay, so if I would specify it as a normal screen, a lot of smart phones will also be supported? I would really like to only have large screen. Is there a place where I can see these specs for which manifest data they are accepted?

Comment: @Marnix I`m really not sure how to support note 2 and not support other normal screens (and not sure if it`s even possible - say thanks to Samsung). Maybe you` ll better start new question for it

Answer (score 0):

I would bet on the following:

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Try updating that ... (maybe remove `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp` or allow `android:normalScreens`) I know that the biggest difference between Note 1 and Note 2 is the screen (size / res / density). That's why I suggest that.

Else, it could be in the generated manifest (all those ${...} get replaced by something else, there could be something wrong there, but you got to find the generated manifest first).

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp` should be removed? The screen is 720x1280.

Comment: Just betting, try and see. Else look at the generated manifest, could be something else.

Comment: And is there an application to test my manifest or do I have to upload my app every time to the app store?

Comment: You can setup an emulator: http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/emulator-size-for-galaxy-note-2-/77/178557 The app won't get installed if the manifest is not compatible.